# Write a lambda function in python via R's reticulate

Tags: r, reticulate

I'm trying to write a simple python function like adding 5 to every item in a column, but I am unable to define a python function within the R environment.  Is it possible to define a Python function within here?

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(reticulate)

os <- import('os')
pd <- import('pandas', convert = F)
np <- import('numpy', convert = F)

a <- pd$Series(data = c(1, 2, 3))

b <- pd$DataFrame(list(a = c(10,20,30),
                       b = c(20, 30, 10)))

c <- pd$DataFrame(list(a = c(10,20,30),
                       c = c(40, 50, 60)))$merge(b)

c$cumsum()

plus_5 <- function(x) x + 5

c$apply(func = plus_5(b$a))
```

Comment: You're "trying to write a simply python function."  Then what happens?

Comment: Misspoke here, but trying to see how a lambda function would work with this R package...

Comment: Your question is un-finished.  You may want to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Python function within R and call it like the following:

```
library(reticulate)
util <- py_run_string("
def f1(a, b=3):
  return a + b
")
util$f1(1)
```

You can then use it in your `c$apply()`. Hope this helps.